# Get the location of the Local IP address of Raspberry pi using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, ip-geolocation

Is there any possible way to get the location of the local IP address of Raspberry Pi by using python language. I am trying with package Geoip, geolocation and google maps but still not able to get any good response.

What I am trying to do here is finding the lat-long of the server which is connected with a [gyroscope sensor](https://store.ncd.io/product/mpu-6000-aka-mpu-6050-6-axis-motiontracking-3-axis-gyroscope-3-axis-accelerometer-digital-motion-processor-i2c-mini-module/) and with the help of IFTTT method I will send the data to email id

Note: I have connected the Raspberry Pi with Wifi for the internet Access

Comment: Are you trying to get location of your rpi based on the communication latency in your local network?

Comment: Well, I don't know about communication latency all, I just need is, to use the local Ip of raspberry pi to get the location using the internet

Comment: It worths mentioning that if you are looking for a really fast and reliable IP geolocation and threat data API, you should have a look at [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) (disclaimer: I run the service): https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout

Answer (score 0):

There are several GeoIP services which have free plans:

- https://ipstack.com/
- https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/
- https://www.ipinfodb.com/api

And here's one which doesn't require an API key: https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/'
r = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.content.decode())
```

That will get you some JSON data with the location of the devices which made the API call.

Comment: HI, Terence Eden, These geoip services shows the location of the main hub IP but not the local Ip of my wifi to get the exact location

Comment: Your Pi's IP address is like to be 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x - those are internal IP addresses. They don't have a physical location. If you need exact coordinates, you will need a USB GPS device attached to the Pi.

Comment: Hi, I was working with node red in RPI today and using GPS module also there is google node available, Is it possible to connect the node red with google credential and search the address?

Comment: Yes - but it will be easiest if you open another question for that. I use https://opencagedata.com/